# R: natural sort of elements in a vector, but certain value always last

Tags: r, sorting, natural-sort

Just trying to do a natural sort of a vector using `gtools::mixedsort`, but I want a certain value to always show up last... is there a clean way to do it? Or should I remove those values from the vector before sorting and then add them manually? Thanks!

In the MWE below I want "na" last:

```
> aa <- c("235dfh","na","addk20","vcxvz89dg","REni0","na","235dfh")
> gtools::mixedsort(unique(aa))
[1] "235dfh"    "addk20"    "na"        "REni0"     "vcxvz89dg"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of hack :

```
aa[aa == 'na'] <- NA
bb <- sort(unique(aa), na.last = TRUE)
bb
#[1] "235dfh"    "addk20"    "REni0"     "vcxvz89dg" NA
```

and then put the value back if needed.

```
bb[is.na(bb)] <- 'na'
#[1] "235dfh"    "addk20"    "REni0"     "vcxvz89dg" "na"
```

---

Or using `setdiff` :

```
c(sort(setdiff(aa, 'na')), 'na')
```

Comment: yeah that's what I thought... pretty much like I was doing: remove before sorting, then add manually

Comment: Yeah. I see `blank.last` and `na.last` option in `mixedsort` but not sure if you can put a specific value as last.